# How to update nextBuildNumber via REST in Jenkins

Tags: rest, jenkins

Is there's a way to update the nextBuildNumber directly via Rest? I found the parameter here:

/job/MyJob/api/xml?tree=nextBuildNumber
and in the job directory, there is a nextBuildNumber file

We already use the Rest Api for creating/updating jobs and views, so it would be nice to stick to this, instead of using cli or the nextbuildnum plugin.

Edit: new approach brings another question

[Java send integer value with HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58100442/java-send-integer-value-with-http-post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST API does not currently (at time of writing) support changing the value of the nextBuildNumber.  As you have found you can (only) read it.

The easiest way I know to manipulate this value is through the [Next Build Number](https://plugins.jenkins.io/next-build-number) plugin.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Can you recommend an easy way to manipulate this value/file? 

We use Groovy & Gradle for creating the complete project setup with jenkins jobs etc. If the project/branch gets deleted, its not getting deleted in real. And if the branch is recreated, the CI Job fails, couse there is already a nextBuildNumber.


We use JenkinsJobBuilder and now im trying to do something like this:

vcs.getRemoteBranchTags(branchName)
cITags = tags.findAll { it.name.contains("CI") }.sort()

Now ive got the Tag "CI-Branch-3" , so the BuildNumber has to be set to 4

Comment: Hi Alexej, I have updated my answer.  Appreciate if you could accept the answer if it helped you out.