# Java send integer value with HTTP POST

Tags: java, http, jenkins, post

Is there's a way to send integers with java/HTTP POST?

This is how the form data should look like:

```
FormData
    nextBuildNumber: 6
    json: {"nextBuildNumber": "6"}
    Submit: Submit
```

We are using Apache HTTP Client. I've tried this:

```
String json = "{\"nextBuildNumber\":10}"
jenkins.httpConnection.requestPost("view/proj/job/nextbuildnumber/submit", json)
```

```
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.requestPost(String request, Map<String, String> values, statusCodeOK = 200)
```

Thus i'm getting this:

```
org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.nextbuildnumber.NextBuildNumberAction.doSubmit(NextBuildNumberAction.java:96)
Caused: javax.servlet.ServletException: Build number must be an integer
```

Comment: `"6"` is a json-string, not an integer.

Comment: but why i'm getting the above errror msg? I've tried out both variants `"6"` and `6` with the same msg

Comment: Have you tried to invoke the service with the same payload by other tools such as Postman?

Comment: Good Idea! I imported our ca-bundle.crt in Postman, but the authentification still fails :S